# Override Clickjack setting for visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, clickjacking

I have a VF page which shows some status value in Home page. In my Org Clickjack is enabled and because of that my VF page is not shown in the Home page. Can anyone tell me how to override the clickjack setting or let me know any other alternative approach. I cannot disable the clickjack option because of the company policy.

Comment: Do you mean home of Salesforce classic view or in Lightning View?

Comment: @Patlatus yes in Home page I want to show a visualforce page which has all Case status.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue some time ago trying to embedded a vf page inside a Standard UI and made it work with below code. It worked in Classic and LEX

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" 
applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">
Testing clickjack inside vf
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi, No luck. Still I am getting "This Content cannot be displayed in frame"

Comment: Sorry are you trying to embedded on the side bar? There is a SF known issue. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4jRAAS

Answer (score 0):

here is one workaround for this issue.

Go to the Session Setting, add the base domain of your org into the white-list domain, that should solve the problem.

For example, the base domain should be something like this:

https://yourdomainname.my.salesforce.com for classic

https://yourdomainname.lightning.force.com for lightning

Good luck~